Is it possible to say that entropy would affect the charge transportation?
I noticed there are a few papers from Dr. Karuppuchamy Navamani, for example:
Generalization on Entropy-Ruled Charge and Energy Transport for Organic Solids and Biomolecular Aggregates
Theoretical modeling of charge transport in triphenylamine–benzimidazole based organic solids for their application as host-materials in phosphorescent OLEDs
In which there is a strange formula (formula 2 of the first paper):
$$ \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}E(\vec{E},\ T)}{\mathrm{d}t} \right\vert_{h_s,S}= \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t} \right\rvert_0 \exp\left(h_s-\frac{S}{k_B}\right)$$
where $\mathrm{d}E/\mathrm{d}t$ is the carrier’s energy transfer rate, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $h_S$ is the differential entropy, and $S$ is the entropy that quantifies the amount of disorder change due to randomness by thermal fluctuation, defect states, and various interactions such as phonon scattering.
This is very strange to me and I am not sure if this formula is right. The first paper that proposed the above formula is in the S50-S57 of the supporting information of Theoretical modeling of charge transport in triphenylamine–benzimidazole based organic solids for their application as host-materials in phosphorescent OLEDs.
But the deduction is very unclear, and there is no one else citing these papers, thus I am left wondering if these formulas and deductions are right.

See: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.01275 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy

Is there any other researchers using the concept of differential entropy to describe the electron structure? @TheTiler

If I compare the general Einstein relationship in semiconductors(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)#Semiconductor) to the formula from equation-7 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.01275, they are not consistent. @TheTiler

I think the equations 1-3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.01275 are important to make the statement from Navamani correct. But he didn't give any explanations how to get these equations. So it comes back to my question. @TheTiler

Sorry, I'm not knowledgeable in the field to give you a satisfactory answer, I'm just an hobbyist in (theoretical) physics.

Can you explain why the formula is strange? You have documented that the formula is new, but is there something about it that violates physical intuition?

According to the final equation, $E$ should be the energy of the charge carriers, but during the deduction (S54 in the hyperlink), $E=k_B*T$ is used based on the energy of the system is expressed in the form of thermal energy.  Is this reasonable? @MitchellPorter
